# Rails Engine : Trouble installing a local gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On an engine (using rails 4), I create some tasks in the lib/tasks repertory, everythings is ok when I use the dummy project.

I generate a gem file and add it to a rails project.

```
gem 'my_gem', '0.0.1', :path => 'vendor/plugins'
```

After the install I did'nt see my tasks using the 'rake -T' command.

When I add a require statement in the application.rb I got an error 'require: cannot load such file'

```
require 'my_gem'
```

So what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.

In fact I wasn't able to load the module inside my gem.

After the install, the '$LOAD_PATH' variable still didn't contained any of my paths.
Now I add my gem in a Rails project using this command :

```
gem install vendor/plugins/my_gem.gem
```

And in the Gemfile I write :

```
gem 'my_gem'
```